# Assembly: access quad-word, double word, and byte quantity of same register in function

Tags: c, assembly, x86-64

I have some assembly code generated from C that I'm trying to make sense of. One part I just can't understand:

```
movslq   %edx,%rcx
movzbl   (%rdi,%rcx,1),%ecx
test     %cl,%cl
```

What doesn't make sense is that `%rcx`, `%ecx`, and `%cl` are all in the same register (quad word, double word, and byte, respectively). How could a data type access all three in the same function like this?

Having a `char*` makes it improbably to access `%ecx` in this way, and similarly having an `int*` makes accessing `%cl` unlikely. I simply have no idea what data type could be stored in `%rcx`.

Comment: _"I simply have no idea what data type could be stored in %rcx"_. The code you've posted uses AT&T syntax, so the operand order is `src, dest`. So the value in `edx` is sign-extended into `rcx`, `rcx` is then used as index into an array of bytes and a value is loaded from that array and zero-extended into `ecx`, and finally the loaded byte is checked to see if it was zero.

Comment: How can you zero-extend into the first 32-bits of a 64-bit data type? Like I said, this would imply `int*` but then you can't check the loaded byte without using some bitwise shift operators.

Answer (score 0):

re: your comment: You can tell it's a byte array because it's scaling `%rcx` by 1.

Like Michael said in a comment, this is doing

```
int func(char *array /* rdi */, int pos /* ecx */)
{
    if (array[pos]) ...;

    // or maybe
    int  tmpi = array[pos];
    char tmpc = tmpi;
    if (tmpc) ...;
}
```

ecx has to get sign-extended to 64bit before being used as an offset in an effective address.  If it was unsigned, it would still need to be zero-extended (e.g. `mov %ecx, %ecx`).  The ABI doesn't guarantee that the upper 32 of a register are zeroed or sign extended when the parameter being passed in a register is smaller than 64bits.

In general, it's better to write at least 32b of a register, to avoid a false dependency on the previous contents on some CPUs.  Only Intel P6/SnB family CPUs track the pieces of integer registers separately (and insert an extra uop to merge them with the old contents if you do something like read `%ecx` after writing `%cl`.)

So it's perfectly reasonable for a compiler to emit that code with the zero-extending `movzbl` load instead of just `mov  (%rdi,%rcx,1), %cl`.  It will potentially run faster on Silvermont and AMD.  (And P4.  Optimizations for old CPUs do hang around in compiler source code...)